# How do I set a attribute to a specific element when using a for loop in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

Below I have a function assigned to a variable. Essentially I got it to work (apply a attribute to a collection of elements). My problem is I'd like the elements which will be set to the attribute, to match the strings which I am passing to the function.

I know the problem is here:

```
document.links[i].setAttribute("target", "_blank"); //this is hitting all links in the document.
```

I'd like just to only change the strings matched in the call:

```
URLChecker.searchURL('smo', 'smodev');
```

**JS:**

```
var URLChecker = (function iffe() {
  var publicAPI = {
        getURL: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                return {
                    'smo': 'http://url.nyc.com',
                    'smodev': 'http://smodev.rye.foo.com',
                    'url1_sans_3w': 'http://url1.com',
                    'url2': 'http://www.url2.com',
                    'url3': 'http://www2.url3.com'
                }[arguments[i]];
            }
        },
        searchURL: function(url) {
            for (var i = 0, l = document.links.length; i < l; i++) {
                var links = document.links[i];
                if (links.href.indexOf(publicAPI.getURL(url) !== -1)) {
                    document.links[i].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
                }
            }
        }
    };
return publicAPI;
})();
```

Call the function like so:

```
URLChecker.searchURL('smo', 'smodev');
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://url.nyc.com">http://url.nyc.com</a>
<br>
<a href="http://smodev.rye.foo.com">http://smodev.rye.foo.com</a>
<br>
<a href="http://url1.com">http://url1.com</a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.url2.com">http://www.url2.com</a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.url3.com">http://www.url3.com</a>
```

Comment: `publicAPI.getURL(url)` returns an object..

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis for indexOf function in this line, right after the call to publicAPI.getURL(url). The right would be:
if (links.href.indexOf(publicAPI.getURL(url)) !== -1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few small logic tweaks are needed to do what you want.  Like this:

```
var URLChecker = (function iffe() {
  var publicAPI = {
        getURL: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                return {
                    'smo': 'http://url.nyc.com',
                    'smodev': 'http://smodev.rye.foo.com',
                    'url1_sans_3w': 'http://url1.com',
                    'url2': 'http://www.url2.com',
                    'url3': 'http://www2.url3.com'
                }[arguments[i]];
            }
        },
        searchURL: function() {
            var link, url;
            for(var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
                url = this.getURL(arguments[i]);
                for (var j = 0, jlen = document.links.length; j < jlen; j++) {
                    link = document.links[j];
                    if (link.href.indexOf(url) !== -1) {
                        link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
return publicAPI;
})();

URLChecker.searchURL('smo', 'smodev');
```

There were just a few issues with how you were checking the url and you needed to loop over both the url and the arguments.

There was also an issue with the indexOf that a parenthesis ended at the wrong position.

JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dkksgcc7/

Comment: Going full code sample was the right approach. Well done.

If you want to try it out, you could use the snippets feature to make it runnable without leaving the page - https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that next time.  So used to JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

One problem in your code is this line:

```
if (links.href.indexOf(publicAPI.getURL(url) !== -1)) {
```

You didn't balance your parentheses quite correctly. Change it to:

```
if (links.href.indexOf(publicAPI.getURL(url)) !== -1) {
```

---

There's a different problem that you didn't ask about yet, but might bite you later.

It looks like you're *trying* return an array of urls from `getUrl`, but you're actually only returning a single string: the result of the first match. If you actually want this to return an array, try this:

```
getURL: function() {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        result.push({
            'smo': 'http://url.nyc.com',
            'smodev': 'http://smodev.rye.foo.com',
            'url1_sans_3w': 'http://url1.com',
            'url2': 'http://www.url2.com',
            'url3': 'http://www2.url3.com'
        }[arguments[i]]);
    }
    return result;
},
```

If you do this, though, you'll have to modify your link filter down below to match. It might look something like this:

```
if (links.href.indexOf(publicAPI.getURL(url)[0]) !== -1) {
```

If this isn't the case, and you just wanted to be able to pass a list of URLs to `getURL` and have it try to match one of them, then no changes are necessary here.

Comment: Wow... we both saw the same problem and came to completely different conclusions.  Good point on the parenthesis issue though.  Maybe OP is trying to see if the url starts with the selected domain?  It seems like OP started with one solution, tried to adapt it and it ended up having a lot of leftover logic.

Comment: I think this actually was intended and works.  He's returning just the one that was asked for.

Comment: @earl3s why parse the argument array in a loop, then? I guess it could be an "any" filter... Updated the answer to account for this possibility.

Comment: In some ways you're right.  My thought was to move the loop to the other function, but either way it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things wrong, but they're easy to fix.  First of all, `URLChecker.searchURL` accepts one parameter and you're passing it two.  Change your function to work with `for(var k in arguments) { ... }` and check against `publicAPI.getURL(arguments[k])` so that you can get all the urls checked.  Secondly, when you check against `links.href`, it normalizes it.  What that means is that you think you're checking "`http://url.nyc.com`" against your array item of "`http://url.nyc.com`", but in reality (at least in chrome) it changes your `href` to "`http://url.nyc.com/`" (note the added slash).  Checking against `links.getAttribute('href')` will fix that.  Lastly, your logic seems off.  You're checking `links.href.indexOf`, but `links.href` isn't an array, you should just need `if (links.getAttribute('href') === publicAPI.getURL(arguments[k]))`.  Final result would be this:

```js
var URLChecker = (function iffe() {
  var publicAPI = {
    getURL: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        return {
          'smo': 'http://url.nyc.com',
          'smodev': 'http://smodev.rye.foo.com',
          'url1_sans_3w': 'http://url1.com',
          'url2': 'http://www.url2.com',
          'url3': 'http://www2.url3.com'
        }[arguments[i]];
      }
    },
    searchURL: function() {
      for(var k in arguments) {
        for (var i = 0, l = document.links.length; i < l; i++) {
          var links = document.links[i];
          if (links.getAttribute('href') === publicAPI.getURL(arguments[k])) {
            document.links[i].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
  return publicAPI;
})();
URLChecker.searchURL('smo', 'smodev');
```

```css
a[target]:after {
  content: '\2197';
}
```

```html
<a href="http://url.nyc.com">http://url.nyc.com</a>
<br>
<a href="http://smodev.rye.foo.com">http://smodev.rye.foo.com</a>
<br>
<a href="http://url1.com">http://url1.com</a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.url2.com">http://www.url2.com</a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.url3.com">http://www.url3.com</a>
```

Comment: `string.indexOf(string)` does a substring search. The change here to remove it will fundamentally change the behavior. That might be fine in this case, though, since the strings seem to match. Totally missed that problem where it was being called with too many arguments.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham Yep.  I think you're on the right track with your logic.  Exact match doesn't make a whole lot of sense if you're providing a list of domains that would trigger it.  It would also help with the issue of `link.href` adding the slash.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a small different approach to your publicAPI object, like this one:

```
var publicAPI = {
    getURL: function(url) {
          var targetUrls = {
                'smo': 'http://url.nyc.com',
                'smodev': 'http://smodev.rye.foo.com',
                'url1_sans_3w': 'http://url1.com',
                'url2': 'http://www.url2.com',
                'url3': 'http://www2.url3.com'
            };

         return targetUrls[url] ? targetUrls[url] : false;
    },

    searchURL: function() {
        var urls = arguments;

        for (var i = 0, l = document.links.length; i < l; i++) {
            var links = document.links[i];

            for (var j=0; j < urls.length; j++) {
                if (links.href.indexOf(publicAPI.getURL(urls[j])) !== -1) {
                    links.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
                }
            }

        }
    }
};
```

It is a bit clear to read, because you are explicitly passing the arguments needed to getURL function one by one instead of making it handle all the arguments that comes from another function.

Try to see if it works.

Comment: Agreed. I'd generally avoid using `arguments` in anything but library-level code. If you don't need to support extremely flexible usage then your code will be much simpler without it.

Comment: Totally agree. The more simple it is, the better it will become.