# How can I strip out a the base URL using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have this function from a previous [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996706/how-do-i-set-a-attribute-to-a-specific-element-when-using-a-for-loop-in-javascri), and it works great however I just realized my collection of links need to have the base URL stripped out.

These are the parts which I thought would strip out the baseURL:

```
baseUrlPattern = /^https?:\/\/[a-z\:0-9.]+/; // create the regexp

link.href.replace(baseUrlPattern ,""); // then use replace to strip it out of the URL
```

**UPDATE**

I should have mentioned:

The function already can discover the link and apply the attribute, but doesn't strip out the base URL.

This:

```
<a href="http://url.nyc.com/xxx/xxx/xxx">link1</a>
```

Should look like this in the DOM afterwards:

```
<a href="/xxx/xxx/xxx" target="_blank">link1</a>
```

**JS:**

```
var URLChecker = (function iffe() {
    var publicAPI = {
        getURL: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                return {
                  'smo': 'http://url.nyc.com',
                  'smodev': 'http://smodev.rye.foo.com',
                  'url1_sans_3w': 'http://url1.com',
                  'url2': 'http://www.url2.com',
                  'url3': 'http://www2.url3.com'
                }[arguments[i]];
            }
        },
        searchURL: function() {
            var link, url, baseUrlPattern = /^https?:\/\/[a-z\:0-9.]+/;
            for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
                url = this.getURL(arguments[i]);
                for (var j = 0, jlen = document.links.length; j < jlen; j++) {
                        link = document.links[j];
                    if (link.href.indexOf(url) !== -1) {
                        link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
                        link.href.replace(baseUrlPattern ,"");

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    return publicAPI;
})();
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://url.nyc.com/xxx/xxx/xxx">link1</a>
<br>
<a href="http://smodev.rye.foo.com/xxx/xxx/xxx">link2</a>
<br>
<a href="http://url1.com/xxx/xxx/xxx">link3</a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.url2.com/xxx/xxx/xxx">link4</a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.url3.com/xxx/xxx/xxx">link5</a>
```

Comment: Can you give example of stripping base url - http://url.nyc.com?

Comment: taking http://url.nyc.com as example, it  should be displayed on the page as url.nyc  right,

Comment: Hi Naga, I have added a bit more of a explanation.

Comment: The [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object does what you want, if the browser support is right.  `new URL("http://www.url2.com/xxx/xxx/xxx").pathname === "/xxx/xxx/xxx"`

Comment: Thanks Noah! Unfortunately, I need something with a lot of support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's different ways you can go about this, here's one of them:

See comments below

```
searchURL: function() {
    var link, url, parser; //added parser
    for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
        url = this.getURL(arguments[i]);
        for (var j = 0, jlen = document.links.length; j < jlen; j++) {
                link = document.links[j];
            if (link.href.indexOf(url) !== -1) {
                // create a dummy link just to get the pathname of the actual link
                parser = document.createElement('a');
                parser.href = link.href;

                link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
                link.href = parser.pathname;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Should you need anything else, remember the `parser` just an anchor so you have the following

```
var href = "http://url.nyc.com/xxx/xxx/xxx"; 
parser = document.createElement('a'); 
parser.href = href; 

console.dir(parser);

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.hostname; // => "url.nyc.com"
parser.port;     // => ""
parser.pathname; // => "/xxx/xxx/xxx"
parser.search;   // => ""
parser.hash;     // => ""
parser.host;     // => "url.nyc.com"
```

Comment: Interesting application of DOM creation

Comment: Thank you eblin, that is pretty clever. I have to go over this more carefully; But I think you are creating a link element so you could eventually copy over the `pathname` to the link you really want? That is sweet!

Answer (score 4):

Using native methods:

```
var url = 'http://url.nyc.com/x/xx/xxx';
var strippedUrl =  new URL(url); // url.pathname == '/x/xx/xxx/'
```

Note: this may not work in Chrome; but browser wasn't specified

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late but if you want

> This:

```
<a href="http://url.nyc.com/xxx/xxx/xxx">link1</a>
```

> Should look like this in the DOM afterwards:

```
<a href="/xxx/xxx/xxx" target="_blank">link1</a>
```

you can do this way

```
var x = 'http://url.nyc.com/xxx/xxx/xxx';
var y = x.split('/').slice(3).join('/');
console.log(y);
```